# Approximately correct

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

*The people you see below share something in common. All together they are **almost** equal to another person.*

### Question:

Who is this person? Explain why.

---

[image]

```
          (5)(3)(3)(4)(2)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The 'almost equal' person is:

> the movie director [Darren Aronofsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darren_Aronofsky).

Because each of the people pictured are:

> movie directors: [Johnnie To](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0864775/), [Anatoliy Mateshko](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0558341/), [Santhosh Viswanath](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm7293846/), and [Joshua Sanchez](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1394837/). (All found by reverse image search - which I suspect was always the intended method as they are *very* obscure...)
>
>  Moreover, they have (respectively) directed the following movies whose titles fit the first four letter counts given in square brackets beneath the images:
>
>  [5] [*Three*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4379728/) (2016)
>  [3] [*Dot*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1542463/) (2009)
>  [3] [*One*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11250720/) (2021)
>  [4] [*Four*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0980999/) (2012)

Considered together - and noting the as-yet unused '[2]' letter count - these would be 'almost equal to'...

> **pi**, the irrational number whose decimal expansion begins 3.14... So we need a director who has made a movie called 'Pi' - Darren Aronofsky's [*Pi*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0138704/) (1998) fits the bill perfectly!

Comment: @hexomino Those are the letter counts I mention at the bottom of my second spoiler :) I'll make that clearer...

Comment: ah yes, you did say +1

Comment: All good, great job!